# Beautiful Soup: Extract data between H2 tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a html text as below

```html
<h2 class="ArticleBody-styles-makeit-subtitle--LnHeO">1. Python</h2>
```

By using Beautiful Soup, how can we extract `1. Python` text ?

I am trying like

```py
data = [ <h2 class="ArticleBody-styles-makeit-subtitle--LnHeO">1. Python</h2> , 
<h2 class="ArticleBody-styles-makeit-subtitle--LnHeO">2. HTML</h2> ]
for item in data :
  text = item.findAll('h2')
  print(text.get_text())
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed `item.findAll('h2')` and modified as below

```
for item in data:
    print(item.get_text())
```

It's working fine now.